# How can I enable both the cameras on the Compute Module 3?

Tags: raspicam, computer-vision, compute-module-3

I am new to using Raspberry Pi devices. I have a problem with enabling the cameras on the Compute Module 3. 
When I run 'vcgencmd get_camera' I get the output 'supported=1, detected=1'.
The connections are all correct as described in Raspberry Pi documentation.

I think I have downloaded the single blob file when I run
`sudo wget http://goo.gl/U4t12b -O /boot/dt-blob.bin`, because the command outputs `supported=1`. Hence I think the problem is with the bin file and not the hardware connections.

How could I enable both the cameras? How to download dt-blob-dualcam.dts?
A detailed command with explanation would help as I am new to this. I couldn't really understand the tree source files document. 
I have also checked out https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=98&t=174347

Am I missing something or did I get anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sudo wget https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule /dt-blob-dualcam.dts
$ sudo dtc -I dts -O dtb -o dt-blob-dualcam.dtb dt-blob-dualcam.dts
$ sudo cp dt-blob-dualcam.dtb /boot/dt-blob.bin
```

This worked for me to enable both the cameras :)

Comment: The link in the your line has an erroneous space. It should be https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/dt-blob-dualcam.dts

Answer (score 1):

I never used compute module with dual camera, but I can show you how to get your missing .dtb file.

First download the dt-blob-dualcam.dts file in our home directory.
`cd`
`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/documentation/master/hardware/computemodule/dt-blob-dualcam.dts`

Next compile it with :
`dtc -I dts -O dtb -o ~/dt-blob-dualcam.dtb ~/dt-blob-dualcam.dts`

Copy th generated dt-blob-dualcam.dtb file in the /boot/overlays folder:
`cp ~/dt-blob-dualcam.dtb /boot/overlays`

Last step tell the system to use this device tree file. Edit /boot/config.txt file and add at the end :
`dtoverlay=dt-blob-dualcam`

Comment: I downloaded dt-blob-dualcam.dts file and its getting downloaded as an audio file. When i compile the next command it says no such file or directories. please help

Comment: Your DTS file is not really an audio file, it's only an extension homonimy.
I'm updating the command line in the answer

Comment: Still it gets downloaded as an audio file :( How could i save it as a .dts file?

Comment: Thanks alot :) Somebody also helped me to find a way. Even if it gets saved as an audio file the contents doesn't change so its fine to continue with the next set of commands.